# SQL Server log in system

Tags: php, sql-server, dreamweaver

Hello i am having trouble connecting to sqlserver 2008 i am trying to create a simple log in system and this is what i have:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION["user_id"])){
        header("location:../../login.html");
    }

?>
<?php
    $username = $_POST[txt_usernmae];
    $user_id = $_POST[txt_password];


    mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die("No Server Found");

    mysql_select_db($schema) or die("No Connection");

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mispelled username

```
$username = $_POST[txt_usernmae];
```

Instead use

```
$username = $_POST['txt_usernmae'];
```

Remember to use '' when you handle POST or GET

Comment: Where would you then put your login details for the server ie your username and password for access tot he server?

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
$username = $_POST[txt_usernmae];
$user_id = $_POST[txt_password];
```

to

```
$username = $_POST['txt_usernmae'];
$user_id = $_POST['txt_password'];
```